# JMETER - TABLE not recognized for SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, jmeter, load-testing

I am using `JMETER` for load testing a `SQL DB` and I tryed to do (in a single JDBC Sampler):

```
IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp') IS NULL  
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmp END        
CREATE TABLE #tmp ( entity numeric(4, 0) NOT NULL, entityCode numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL, entityTraceabilityDeclared numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL )      
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_#tmp_entityCode_entity ON #tmp ( entityCode, entity )      
{CALL   entityTraceability_UpdatePieceLastMovement       }
```

But i got a error saying "invalid object name #tmp"

If i do

```
SELECT * FROM #tmp
```

Instead of calling the sp it works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a temporary table by using # in the front. This means it will only be available in the exact session it was created in. It will not be visible by any sessions you create outside of jmeter or in fact any sessions in jmeter that aren't the session that issued the create (in case you are creating multiple threads).

I noticed you are using `.dbo.` in `tempdb.dbo.#tmp` which could be an issue if `dbo` is not the default database. Might want to use `tempdb..#tmp` instead since temps go there.

Also, you could maybe print out `@@SPID` to make sure that you are actually doing things in the sessions you think you are.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks! did not know how temporary tables work, i will try to fix it now

Comment: I tryed to do:

Select * from #tmp 

And it works (in the same JDBC Sampler where I create the table)

But when I do this:

IF NOT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp') IS NULL  
 BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmp END   


CREATE TABLE #tmp ( entity numeric(4, 0) NOT NULL, entityCode numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL, entityTraceabilityDeclared numeric(18, 0) NOT NULL )   
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_#tmp_entityCode_entity ON #tmp ( entityCode, entity )  

{CALL entityTraceability_UpdatePieceLastMovement   }

Comment: Try referencing `tempdb..#tmp` instead?  Not sure?  Might be due to default schema?

Comment: Any luck with my last suggestion?

Comment: Sorry I did not answer you before. I could not try it yet because i was leaving work. I am going to try it on monday and let you know. It is weird that does not work, because I copy that from the log of the application that I want to test, and in JMETER does not work. but I will try your suggestion of using " tempdb..#tmp".

 Thanks!!!

Comment: I did what you say but I have no luck. Here are some screenshots of what I am getting.

With this: ( https://s31.postimg.org/tm1dtp4p7/RL1.png)  I got java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name '#tmp'.

Without the last procedure call It does not fail and I get this: ( https://s32.postimg.org/fv9ru0yx1/rl2.png) 

The procredure that is failing is:   (https://s31.postimg.org/j4bp6cb9n/SP_QUE_FALLA.png)

Comment: Could you add @@SPID check inside the sp?

Comment: I don't know sql server that well anymore. It's been awhile, but can you do an anonymous block?  `{ begin select @@SPID; call ...; end }`